# Video Paused but its sound still trailing

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'm building a winstore app and building a skip-able intro (dynamically added it through JavaScript code).

However, if i skip it and set

```
this.video.pause();
```

in the button click function, even though the video is paused, the sound of the video is still trailing for a few sec before it stopped.

**How could i make the sound stop right there with the images?**

It's just weird that the video is already paused but the sound still can be heard when it should've been paused too (the video contain mp4 and mp3 in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird because if a video is really paused it off the image and sound.
You can try this following command (it cut the sound) :

```
this.video.setAttribute("muted", "muted");
```

But it's not the solution because pause() method should work, so checks if you don't have 2 videos elements in your page.

Comment: okay, this is weird. i try add that code to my `onClick()`, yet, the sound still trails off. I've checked the pause state of the video and it return `true`. However, if i added the code within the function that set the src (i added the src dynamically), it works... just not in different function is all... even though it i use a global variable: `var vid = document.getElementById('videoID');`